# HTTP 404 in style="-webkit-mask-image: url()" with angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, url

I need to specify a *templated link* to a mask image in style using css `url()` function. The code is like this:

`<div class="someclass" style="-webkit-mask-image: url('https://img.website.com/{{imagefilename}}.png')">`

It generates 404 errors while "imagefilename" is not replaced with it's value. Is there a way to avoid this behavior, similar to replacing `src` with `ng-src` in `<img>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ng-style instead of style. ng-style needs to be an object. Might be easier to format in controller.

```
// In controller 
$scope.setStyle = function(url){
    return {
        “webkit-mask-image”: “url(“ + url + “)”
    };
};
```

Also, the URL for  -webkit-mask-image: url( ) should not be enclosed with parentheses. Via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/12676/star.svg);
mask-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/12676/star.svg);
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the hint. ```<div class="someclass" ng-style="{'-webkit-mask-image': 'url(https://img.website.com/{{imagefilename}}.png)'}">``` worked for me!